# What causes Website timeout when it is working flawlessly with vpn?

Tags: php, timeout, vpn

I have some php (php 7.4) program that is connected to a Webserver that causes problems when I do not use a VPN.

Sadly, we just using the server without any rights to config it.
So if you need something specific I can ask for this Information.

#### There are some Serverinformations

### DB-Server

Server-Type: MariaDB

Server-Version: 10.4.20 MariaDB - MariaDB Server

### Webserver

Apache/2.4.37(centos)

PHP-Ext: mysqli, curl, mbstring

PHP-Version: 7.3.20

### phpinfo():

PHP 7.4.18

Other People testing the program getting same results.
My php program is working flawlessly with VPN and local.

Now here is the issue:
It is some straight-forward program. You need to answer the questions to get further and after some time you can end the program. A Survey, you can start it by typing the URL in any Browser you find.

#Thats bringing me to this point#

Program interrupts randomly (no specific site or element) while work through. Leaving TimeOut Website and deprecated non-js Modules console-message. Apparently things are deprecated.

#Now I use VPN# 
Program does not interrupt at any point. This procedure is working for every Person testing the Program. This means, I do not get the message "deprecated non-js modules".
Either things are not deprecated or there are other reasons making the Program work without timeout.

##### Error-Code

### Website

ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

### Console of Chrome

VM9:7146 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

##### My Doings and Ideas:

- I checked the whole Program for deprecated elements, tags, functions...

-> Using PHPStorm and:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1)
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1)
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

-> There were something. Every used deprecated something could be replaced easily. Lucky me.

- IP-Adress is stable while working through the program.
- Program is working local. Tested it 50 times without any interruptions.
- Program is working with VPN. Tested it...
- Session variables expire after 6 hours.
- classic mysqli_connect.
- session cookies.
- using css and js files.
- using other php files for configs and better organisation.

####New Facts

1. I tested some other php program (more complex - needed to add "preventDefault()" to make it work for Chrome/Safari). Using same files and every function of the contaminated php program. And no timeouts without VPN. 
   -> Now I think it is the specific program. But why? There is nothing new in use.

Differences:

 The corrupted program shows some text and answer options you need to click to get to the next site. Website timeouts occur randomly when I press the radio button to send the value.

New program shows also some text and these answer options. But you can interact with it. After you press the radio button, you get pictures and buttons which are telling you what to do. I added a simple event handler (js) to show these pictures and buttons and hide em (depends on the condition the program gives you). It is using the same functions to send values, present pictures/texts, hop to the next page. It has generally more pages, therefore more texts, pictures.

2. The VPN I use must be very close to the server. But cannot tell for sure. It is something like an university-vpn to access specific things.
3. Tested it with handy-network (5G). No timeouts! I asked people to test it, so we get some stability-statistics.

It is important that people (not only me) outside this vpn-network can access the program and end it successfully!
Can you show me some lead I can follow?

Thank you. :)

Comment: Seems like more of a network issue than anything specific to PHP or the server (unless its firewall is playing a part in this perhaps)

Comment: `My php program is working flawlessly with VPN and for people with DSL-Internet.`...ok so who exactly doesn't it work for then? People with 3G/4G mobile connections? People on corporate networks? It's not very clear.

Comment: Hello!

the program is working on 4 device connected to DSL-Internet.
It is not working for me and 5 other people with vodafone cable internet.
It is working on all internets and devices with vpn.
The program wasn't meant to work on Mobile Fons. 
But I need to test this -> Good advice, thank you :)

I deactived Firewall. Deinstalled all Virusscans. And deleted all extensions on my chrome Browser.

Comment: I was thinking of the firewall on the server (or its network) actually. Are you located in the same country as the server? If not, which countries are involved? National firewalls might also play a part, depending - that's often why VPNs are used, to get around such problems.

Comment: It's the same country. You mean some security on the server? Actually I do not know this. But I missed that point. I contacted today someone who knows the server. He couldn't help me, but will ask around for some Information. 

I keep you updated. Hope that is not taking to long.

Comment: Actually, I was wondering about the fact that elements of the program are deprecated if I don't use VPN. It is pretty hypothetical, but is there a Software-Difference between 1) Connecting over a VPN which is very close to the server 2) Connecting over a random private Internet to the server?

Apparently things are not deprecated if I use this locally near VPN.
This error message must come from somewhere, no?

Comment: So, hang on, are you saying you can't get to any part of the site from your cable internet, or it's just one particular page which times out?

Comment: Program interrupts randomly (no specific site or element) while work through. Leaving TimeOut Website and deprecated non-js Modules console-message. Apparently things are deprecated.

Using VPN makes the program work for every testing person. This means I do not get the message "non-js modules are deprecated". Things are no longer deprecated or there are other reasons why I don't get this deprecated-message.

Comment: VPN itself doesn't cause software to be deprecated. Can you show a screenshot of this message?

Comment: Sure! Thank you for your time.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UccSK.jpg

Comment: It's not even loading your page, so the Javascript error cannot be from your own code, it must be from the error page (because that's a html document too, it's just one that Chrome provides). So that error is not relevant I think.

Comment: I would guess that maybe the server or its network is unstable and/or overloaded, although in that case it's hard to understand why it always works consistently with the VPN...do you know if the VPN exit point is geographically nearer to your server, or further away, or which ISP it uses? I was originally going to say this was a problem with your cable provider but now you seem to be saying it's a problem for users on multiple different providers, so it's a bit more of a mystery. Any luck testing from a mobile 3G/4G connection?

Comment: You are right. I do not understand the use of the term "deprecated" when it isn't referring to deprecated tags, elements, functions...

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, contacting the server-support.
Firewall rules are very strict and blacklisted people who are testing the program with >1 click per second. Apparently that is the behavior of a bot.

That explains also the working other php-program, which uses same functions, files, everything. There, you couldn't be faster than 1 click per second because you need to wait for some elements to show you what to do before sending produced values.

Special thanks to ADyson! :)